# Store form values in sessions array

Tags: php, arrays, session

In page1.php a user can enter a day name and it stores in session array called days.

```
<?
// starting the session
session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['days'] = $_POST['days'];
} 
?> 

<strong>Add a day</strong>
<form action="" method"post">
    <input type="text" name="days[]"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<p><a href="/test/page2.php">Page 2</a></p>
```

The in page2.php, a user can check which days it has entered:

```
<?php
session_start();
// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['days'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    // and print out the values
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```

But I cant make the session connection correct, it is just blank. 
Is this the correct way of handling sessions with arrays?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to session_start() in page2.php and $_SESSION != $_session

Comment: Replace all occurences of $_session with $_SESSION  .
$_session is not equal to the magic superglobal $_SESSION, its basically just some array you define.

Comment: updated but I get this error now: "The requested URL /test/page2.php was not found on this server." I havent code so when you sumbit a value you would be redirected to page2.php. Does it have something to do with that?

Comment: its obviously some wrong path in the link or wherever, or the blank action="" in the form. you should be able to figure that out yourself, since we neither know what you're trying to do nor where your files lay.

Comment: yeah, but there is nothing wrong wiht my dir.. something is fishy with the code..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13557/discussion-between-mightyuhu-and-shumacupcake)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you forgetting the session_start() in the second page?

Also, why don't you post the values to the second page and use the $_POST instead of putting them in a session first?